# FFMPEG scaling error-invalid dimension

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, libavcodec, swscale

I'm working on a Project in FFMPEG, and right now i'm stuck on a Problem.

What i am trying to do is, convert a png pic in to a mpeg Video file. I've already managed to take informatin from the Picture, but somehow i cannot convert the Picture in YUV Format. It returns "0x0->0x0 is invalid scaling dimensions".

Here'S my code:

```
 AVFrame *pFrame;
AVFrame *pFrameYUV;
pFrame = av_frame_alloc();
pFrameYUV = av_frame_alloc();
int numBytes;//Groesse des Bildes
uint8_t *buffer= NULL;
numBytes=avpicture_get_size(AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, pCodecCtx->width,pCodecCtx->height); 
buffer=(uint8_t *)av_malloc(numBytes*sizeof(uint8_t)); 

/*avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)pFrameYUV, buffer, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,
                pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);*/
av_image_fill_arrays(pFrameYUV->data,pFrameYUV->linesize,buffer,AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,pCodecCtx->width,pCodecCtx->height,32);


struct SwsContext *sws_ctx = NULL;

AVPacket packet;
// initialize SWS context for software scaling
sws_ctx=sws_getCachedContext(NULL,pFrame->width,pFrame->height,AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24,pFrameYUV->width,pFrameYUV->height,AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,0,0,0,0);
pFrameYUV->height= pFrame->height;
pFrameYUV->width= pFrame->width;

while (av_read_frame(pFormatCtx,&packet)>=0)
{
    if(packet.stream_index == videoStream)
    {
        avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet); 

        if(frameFinished)
        {

        sws_scale(sws_ctx, (uint8_t const * const *)pFrame->data,
          pFrame->linesize, 0, pCodecCtx->height,
          pFrameYUV->data, pFrameYUV->linesize);
        printf("%d",pFrameYUV->height);

    }
    }
    av_free_packet(&packet);
}
```

EDIT:

After the converting, i tried to encode the Frame in o a packet, but he size of the packet is 0.
Code

```
AVPacket pkt;
av_init_packet(&pkt);
pkt.stream_index= st->index;
pkt.data= buffer;
pkt.size=numBytes;
int got_pkt;
test=avcodec_encode_video2(st->codec,&pkt,pFrameYUV,&got_pkt);

printf("%d",got_pkt);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These values `pFrameYUV->height, pFrame->height, pFrameYUV->width, pFrame->width` didn't set when calling `sws_getCachedContext`.

Do you mean the dimension not changing? If so, set them before `sws_getCachedContext`.

```
pFrameYUV->height = pFrame->height = pCodecCtx->height;
pFrameYUV->width = pFrame->width = pCodecCtx->width;
sws_ctx=sws_getCachedContext(NULL,pFrame->width,pFrame->height,AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24,pFrameYUV->width,pFrameYUV->height,AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,0,0,0,0);
```

Comment: I thought those wee set with av_image_fill_Arrays? Do i have to set the pix fmt of the Frame as well?

Comment: Yes, you should set the `pix_fmt` as well for safety.

Comment: Hey, it works. But the data field of pFrameYUV is still empty after the scaling. How do i set it?

Comment: `sws_scale` will fill for you. You should check the return value `avcodec_decode_video2` with `frameFinished` to make sure the decode of frame successfully.

Comment: Decoding is succesful, Frame is finished but the data field of pFrameYUV is still empty

Comment: Okay, uncomment this line `avpicture_fill`. `av_image_fill_arrays` will not allocate `AVFrame` memory for you.

Comment: According to the documentation avpicture_fill is deprecated, and av_Image_fill_Arrays should be used.

Comment: Another weird Thing is, when i try to encode the pFrameYUV, it still says that i Need to use av_send_Frame instead. And when i call av_send_Frame i Returns -22( which is error)

Comment: If it's deprecated, use `av_image_alloc` instead `av_image_fill_arrays` to allocate `AVFrame` memory. Yes, new api is `av_send_frame` and `av_receive_packet`. Changing to the new one.

Comment: How do i actually check, if data from pFrame is copied to pFrameYUV?

Comment: `sws_scale` will return the height if successfully. there is no better way to check as far as I know.

Comment: I tried to copy the Frame to a packet using av_inerleaved_write_Frame. The size of the packet is 0, it means there s nothing in pFameYUV

Comment: Without seeing your code, I couldn't figure out what happened in your code.

Comment: `AVPacket` should be filled by the encoder. `pkt.data = NULL;
pkt.size = 0;`

Comment: It does no work. I think the Problem is the sws_scale

Comment: Change this line `avpicture_get_size(AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, pCodecCtx->width,pCodecCtx->height);`

Comment: There s absolutely nothing in the data of pFrameYUv, thats the Problem.